# how to access MySQL databbase from one computer to another computer in window 7

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have installed MySQL by this installer **mysql-installer-community-5.6.17.0.msi** on my pc and I am able to add database `Shop` using MySQL workbench.

my problem is how to use this `shop` database to another computer i mean how to use this database remotly.

please explain me easy step i am new in mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external server running mysql, just use the ip address of the server to access the mysql server. Same goes with accessing your mysql server from your home network.

There is a problem that could occur when trying to access your "home" made mysql server from the internet because of port forwarding issues, but unless this is the case you don't have to worry about it.

Steps to follow (suggesting you are in a home network):

1) Open command prompt on your mysql server.

2) Type ipconfig you should see something similar to this. IPv4 Adress .... 192.168.0.xxx

3) Thats the ip adress you will need to acces the mysql server.

You need to do the following before attempting to connect from ASP.NET to MySQL database:

1) Make sure you have installed the .Net Framework on your server

2) Download the ODBC .Net data provider and install it on your development machine or your server. You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6ccd8427-1017-4f33-a062-d165078e32b1&DisplayLang=en

3) install MySQL ODBC Driver-MyODBC 3.51. You can download it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html

Next up is following a tutorial: [Found here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/mysql/getting-started/)

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for reply..when i am selecting "MySQL Database (MySQL Data Provider)" inside server explorer in asp.net and puting servername="121.11.1.1",username=root,password="sa"  but still showing error message like "unable to connect any of spcified mysql"

Comment: when i am trying to access mysql database from different pc then getting error message like "Host 'compuetname' is not allowed to connect to this MYSQL-server".pls help me out

Comment: I'm not sure if these problems are related to the subject but if you like I can assist you with teamviewer or something.